# How to append div using $(this) selector in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I have two div tag which is created dynamically at runtime. That tag class name is `MainFolder`

```
<div class="MainFolder" style="padding-left: 20px; width: 200px; height: 23px;">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close folder-icon"></span>Folder1<br>
</div>
<div class="MainFolder" style="padding-left: 20px; width: 200px; height: 23px;">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close folder-icon"></span>Folder2<br>
</div>
```

On click function in Jquery

```
$(document).on('click', '.MainFolder', function () {

    $('<div id="outer">Outer Div Content<div id="inner">Inner Div Content</div></div>').appendTo($(this).parent());
    //$('<div id="outer">Outer Div Content<div id="inner">Inner Div Content</div></div>').appendTo($(this));
    //$(this).appendTo('<div id="outer">Outer Div Content<div id="inner">Inner Div Content</div></div>');
});
```

I want to create the div tag under the selected element.

I am trying to make div element under the one of div tag where user clicked

If I try this below code.
It is creating on both folder. But when I use $(this),its not working

```
$('<div id="outer">Outer Div Content<div id="inner">Inner Div Content</div></div>').appendTo('.MainFolder');
```

Comment: Please state your actual issue that you are facing.

Comment: @gurvinder372 I want to create div tag inside of one div tag(.MainFolder) where user clicked

Comment: Just append to `this`, then. No need for `parent()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append to `$(this)` instead of the parent element of clicked `MainFolder`

```
  $('<div id="outer">Outer Div Content<div id="inner">Inner Div Content</div></div>').appendTo($(this));
```

Also, remove the `height` style from the `MainFolder`

**Demo**

```js
$(document).on('click', '.MainFolder', function() {

  $('<div id="outer">Outer Div Content<div id="inner">Inner Div Content</div></div>').appendTo($(this));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="MainFolder" style="padding-left: 20px; width: 200px;">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close folder-icon"></span>Folder1<br>
</div>
<div class="MainFolder" style="padding-left: 20px; width: 200px;">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close folder-icon"></span>Folder2<br>
</div>
```

**Edit**

Looks like you are making an ajax call after on click, so save a reference to `$(this)`

```
$(document).on('click', '.MainFolder', function() {
  var $self = $(this);
  $('<div id="outer">Outer Div Content<div id="inner">Inner Div Content</div></div>').appendTo($self);
});
```

Comment: I removed the height from the Mainfolder. But still it doesn't show anything

Comment: @kevinPeter Did the demo (shared in my post) not worked for you?

Comment: it throws this error on Jquery.js file `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined`

Comment: no it's not working. Actually I am calling ajax when user click the MainFolder. If the result is  success, it has to create div. The result is success. i got the alert message

Comment: Share the actual code that you tried in a fiddle. Otherwise I am unable to make out why your code is failing.

Comment: I got the alert, it brings the record from server. the result is also success

Comment: @kevinPeter Most likely your issue is due to `this` pointing to the ajax's function context instead of clicked element. You need to save $(this) to self and append to self

Comment: can you tell me how?

Answer (score 0):

have checked at jsfiddle. it works.

```
   $('body').on('click', '.MainFolder', function(){
        var html = '<div id="outer">Outer Div Content<div id="inner">'+
        'Inner Div Content</div></div>';
        var self = $(this);
      self.parent().append(html);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Change From

```
$('<div id="outer">Outer Div Content<div id="inner">Inner Div Content</div></div>').appendTo($(this).parent());
```

to

```
$('<div id="outer">Outer Div Content<div id="inner">Inner Div Content</div></div>').appendTo($(this));
```